# Why is the type checking in Dart such strange?

Tags: flutter, generics, dart, typechecking, compile-time-type-checking

Given code

```
List<int> rawList = [0, 1, 2];
BuiltList<int> list = rawList.map((n) => n * 2);
```

compiles successfully but fails at runtime with the error

> type 'MappedListIterable<int, int>' is not a subtype of type
> 'BuiltList'

So why wouldn't it crash on compile stage? Please explain, after C# and Kotlin I can't understand that.

Comment: That code gives me compile time errors actually (at least IDE shows that its wrong)

Comment: What is the declaration of the `BuildList`?

Comment: @BambinoUA it's from built_collection https://pub.dev/packages/built_collection

Answer (score 1):

`.map` returns an `Iterable<int>`, which doesn't fit in your `List<int>`.  You need to convert the `Iterable` to a `List` with `.toList()`.

Comment: Yes, a List is an Iterable, so a List can be used wherever you want an Iterable.  But you have the other direction: you want an Iterable to behave like a List.  No go. Hence requiring the extra .toList().

Comment: @BambinoUA My guess is it isn't breaking Liskov Substitution Principle

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thank you but I understand the reason of the error. My question is why is it a runtime error but not a compile time.

Comment: Dunno.  Maybe there's something in NNBD to enforce that better.